# Searching for a data with purchase order number and displaying them in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "-----"

```
    Dim SqlString1 As String = "select * from tbl_po where prno='" & textboxall.Text & "' and rev='" & TextBoxrev.Text & "'"

    If ComboBox1.Text = "PR No. & Rev." Then
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlString1, conn)
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
        conn.Close()
        If (DataGridView2.Rows.Count > 1) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Found")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No Record Found")
        End If
    End If
```

The program isn't displaying anything in the gridview only the colums headers
can you please help me?

Comment: `conn.open()` and `conn.Close()` are not necesary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out..

```
Dim SqlString1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from tbl_po where prno='" & textboxall.Text & "' and rev='" & TextBoxrev.Text & "'", conn)

If ComboBox1.Text = "PR No. & Rev." Then
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlString1)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    conn.Open()
    da.Fill(ds, "Table")
    DataGridView2.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView2.DataMember = "Table"
    conn.Close()
    If (DataGridView2.Rows.Count > 1) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Record Found")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No Record Found")
    End If
End If
```